# Pull-ups: go all the way down?

Tags: pull-ups

Should you go all the way down when doing pull-ups or chin-ups? Or should you stop when your arms are at 90 degrees?

Comment: @gwaigh: That question is about injuries to the shoulder. I want to know about effect on the muscles.

Comment: What is your concern about the range of motion?  What outcome are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PierreB - I tend to agree that it is a duplicate. While there is mention of pain, the main question is "Is there any benefit to locking out shoulders", and that is the main focus of all the answers.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the harder = the better. Going up and then all the way down is a harder variation and it has a better effect on muscle growth.